# post_object fields don't work any more after including ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

After I included ACF into my Plugin fields of type 'user' and 'post_object' don't work any more. They worked perfectly fine before I included ACF. They are displayed but they don't show me any options any more. Any clue what this might have caused? I guess that some link might have changed but I can't find any hint to that in the code:

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_local_field_group') ):

acf_add_local_field_group(array(
    'key' => 'group_5f65057cd8301',
    'title' => 'Employees Details',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'field_5f8a0c6792e45',
            'label' => 'Display Name',
            'name' => 'display_name',
            'type' => 'user',
            'instructions' => '',
            'required' => 1,
            'conditional_logic' => 0,
            'wrapper' => array(
                'width' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'role' => array(
                0 => 'employee',
                1 => 'administrator',
            ),
            'allow_null' => 0,
            'multiple' => 0,
            'return_format' => 'array',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'field_5f65089dbbe1d',
            'label' => 'Occupation',
            'name' => 'occupation',
            'type' => 'post_object',
            'instructions' => '',
            'required' => 1,
            'conditional_logic' => 0,
            'wrapper' => array(
                'width' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'post_type' => array(
                0 => 'occupations',
            ),
            'taxonomy' => '',
            'allow_null' => 0,
            'multiple' => 0,
            'return_format' => 'object',
            'ui' => 1,
        ), 
array(
            'key' => 'field_5f8b42ca6c4c6',
            'label' => 'Costs per Hour',
            'name' => 'costs_per_hour',
            'type' => 'number',
            'instructions' => 'Enter a number with max 2 decimals, separated by ".", e.g. "35.46"',
            'required' => 0,
            'conditional_logic' => 0,
            'wrapper' => array(
                'width' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'min' => '',
            'max' => '',
            'step' => '0.01',
        ),
    ),
    'location' => array(
        array(
            array(
                'param' => 'post_type',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => 'employees',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'menu_order' => 0,
    'position' => 'acf_after_title',
    'style' => 'default',
    'label_placement' => 'top',
    'instruction_placement' => 'label',
    'hide_on_screen' => '',
    'active' => true,
    'description' => '',
));

endif;
```

In the meantime I found this:

In the console there are errors as these:
Failed to load resource: the server responded .../advanced-custom-fields/assets/css/acf-global.css?ver=5.9.1
ReferenceError:Can't find variable: acf Global Code post-new.php 1972
(actually my post-new.php doesn't even have so many lines)

When I click on the last one the debugger gives me this:
acf.data = {"postboxes":[{...
acf.doAction( 'prepare' )

And when I finally look into the apache_error.log there are errors like:
File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myPlugin/Applications, referrer: http://localhost:8888/myPlugin/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=jobs

Comment: This is not the full code for this function maybe thats the issue?

Comment: I added the rest of the function above. I didn't suspect it to be relevant. If I change post_type to 'posts' or 'pages' I still don't get any matches. Seems to me that the link to the chosen post_types doesn't work. Unfortunately I have no idea where to find that link.